# Function assigning values after it returns Swift

Tags: swift, function, closures

I'm running into a weird bug where my function appends a value to an array AFTER it returns... The code for this is below :

```
func makeUser(first: String, last: String, email: String) -> [User] {

    var userReturn = [User]()

    RESTEngine.sharedEngine.registerUser(email, firstName: first, lastName: last, age: 12, success: { response in
        if let response = response, result = response["resource"], id = result[0]["_id"] {

            let params: JSON =
            ["name": "\(first) \(last)",
             "id": id as! String,
             "email": email,
             "rating": 0.0,
             "nuMatches": 0,
             "nuItemsSold": 0,
             "nuItemsBought": 0]
             let user = User(json: params)

            userReturn.append(user)
            print("\(userReturn)")

        }
        }, failure: { error in
            print ("Error creating a user on the server: \(error)")
    })

    return userReturn
}
```

I call make user from here:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    var newUser = makeUser("Average", last: "Person", email: "a.Person@mail.com")
    print("\(newUser)")
}
```

(This is all still testing so I'm obviously calling my code in weird places.)

So when I run this what ends up happening is that FIRST my "newUser" array gets printed (and it shows up empty), and afterwards the userReturn array that I assign locally within the makeUser function prints, and it contains the new user that I append to it within the "success" completion block of "registerUser", like so: 
[image]

Does anyone know whats happening here, and how I could fix it?

For reference: JSON is simply a typealias I defined for [String: AnyObject] dictionary.

Comment: Because `RESTEngine.sharedEngine.registerUser` run asynchronously?

Comment: When the actual request is sent, it is asynchronous, but isn't that what needs to happen? Asynchronously means it stops the code from proceeding further, and ensures I have some form of response before I continue, no?

Comment: @DavidTamrazov - No, it means the exact opposite. It means that it will not stop the current thread while the request runs asynchronously. So you can't (or at least shouldn't try to) return the value. You need to adopt asynchronous pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `registerUser` runs asynchronously, so you should apply asynchronous pattern, such as completion handler:

```
func makeUser(first: String, last: String, email: String, completionHandler: ([User]?, ErrorType?) -> ()) {
    RESTEngine.sharedEngine.registerUser(email, firstName: first, lastName: last, age: 12, success: { response in
        if let response = response, result = response["resource"], id = result[0]["_id"] {
            var users = [User]()

            let params: JSON =
            ["name": "\(first) \(last)",
             "id": id as! String,
             "email": email,
             "rating": 0.0,
             "nuMatches": 0,
             "nuItemsSold": 0,
             "nuItemsBought": 0]
            let user = User(json: params)
            users.append(user)

            completionHandler(users, nil)
        } else {
            let jsonError = ...  // build your own ErrorType or NSError indicating that the the parsing of the JSON failed for some reason
            completionHandler(nil, jsonError)
        }
    }, failure: { error in
        completionHandler(nil, error)
    })
}
```

And use it like so:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    makeUser("Average", last: "Person", email: "a.Person@mail.com") { users, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        print("\(users)")
        // if you're doing anything with this, use it here, e.g. reloadTable or update UI controls
    }

    // but don't try to use `users` here, as the above runs asynchronously
}
```

Comment: Ah all right I gotcha, I didn't know asynchronous calls had to be handled through completion blocks. Thank you Rob!

Comment: So if in the completion block of "makeUser" as you have it above, if I want to return the new user object I made, would I need to pass it to another function?

Comment: @DavidTamrazov - Then you'd put the call to that other function inside the completion block of `makeUser` (e.g. where I said "if you're doing anything with this, use it here...").

Comment: I created such a function and made the call within the makeUser completion block but I'm still running into the same issue, unfortunately.

Comment: Then you should edit your question (or perhaps better, create new question) and show us the method that you're calling. It's impossible to diagnose without seeing what you're doing and precisely what behavior you're experiencing (eg what error you got or what have you).