# Trouble returning a variable from within a completion block:

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, closures

I'm using the functions below to get some data from my server through the RESTEngine.sharedEngine.registerUser function. "userCreationCall" makes API call, parses the JSON it gets back, makes a user and then passes that user along in its completion block.

"makeUser" then handles that completion block by passing the user within it to another function that returns the user object for me to use elsewhere in my app.

```
func userCreationCall(first: String, last: String, email: String, completionHandler: (User?, ErrorType?) -> ()) {
RESTEngine.sharedEngine.registerUser(email, firstName: first, lastName: last, age: 12, success: { response in
    if let response = response, result = response["resource"], id = result[0]["_id"] {            
        let params: JSON =
        ["name": "\(first) \(last)",
            "id": id as! String,
            "email": email,
            "rating": 0.0,
            "nuMatches": 0,
            "nuItemsSold": 0,
            "nuItemsBought": 0]
        let user = User(json: params)
        completionHandler(user, nil)
    }
    }, failure: { error in
        completionHandler(nil, error)
    })
}

func makeUser(first: String, last: String, email: String) {

    userCreationCall(first, last: last, email: email) { user, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("Error creating a user! : \(error)")
            return
        }

        returnUser(user!)
    }
}

func returnUser(user: User) -> User {
    return user
}
```

For testing purposes I make the following call in viewDidLoad, intending for "testUser" to be assigned the user object passed within the completion block of "makeUser":

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()  
    let testUser = makeUser("John", last: "Doe", email: "johnDoe@gmail.com")
    print("\(testUser)")
}
```

However, when I print testUser, it still comes up blank (meaning it never gets assigned the user object within "makeUser"'s completion block). Does anyone have a clue as to where my logic/implementation went wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should use completion handler in `makeUser` too with what output you want instead of doing return.

Comment: You took `makeUser` from [that other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37887015/1271826), but don't seem to have understood the fundamental point, that you cannot return the value from an asynchronous method (and `getUser` is now asynchronous method). When calling asynchronous methods, don't try to return results, but rather always follow asynchronously programming patterns, such as completion handler pattern.

Comment: You say "it never gets assigned the user object within "makeUser"'s completion block". No, it does get a value, but later, after `viewDidLoad` is already done. You can only use the value in the completion block, not in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: so since I cannot return a value from an asynchronous method, it seems my only remaining option would be to have an "empty" user object declared before my asynchronous call, that I would fill in with the data I get from the response. Is my thinking correct here?

Comment: Yep, that's the way to do it. If you can, save what it was the last time, so you have something to show while it's getting refreshed with newer data. Or show an activity indicator view while it's performing the asynchronous request.

Answer (score 0):

You need also a completion block in `makeUser` for example

```
func makeUser(first: String, last: String, email: String, completion:((User?) -> Void)) {

  userCreationCall(first, last: last, email: email) { user, error in
    guard error == nil else {
        print("Error creating a user! : \(error)")
        completion(nil)
        return
    }

    completion(user)
  }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()  
    makeUser("John", last: "Doe", email: "johnDoe@gmail.com") { user in 
       if user != nil {
          print("\(user!)")
       }
    }
}
```

---

But the extra function is actually not needed

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    userCreationCall("John", last: "Doe", email: "johnDoe@gmail.com") { user, error in
      if error != nil {
         print("Error creating a user! : \(error!)")
      } else {
         print("\(user!)")
         // do something with the new created user
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: So I suppose whats confusing me is how could I use the information obtained from the userCreationCall (i.e. user) in creating a local user variable on my app? Would I need to have an "empty" uninitialized user created just before I call "userCreationCall", and then in its completion block use the data from the call to assign my "empty" user its properties?

Comment: Exactly, since the data is retrieved asynchronously you have to assign the value in the completion block.

Comment: Okay fair enough. I'm still struggling with this because I'm trying to find a way to incorporate a "user return" in these blocks. Essentially what I'm trying to make happen is allow my front-end guys to be able to call "makeUser", pass it some basic info, and get back a User object obtained with Data from the server without ever having to worry about completion blocks or backend implementation. Any suggestion on how to implement this?

Comment: Try to understand and get use to the asynchronous pattern. Loading data from a server could always take some time and for good user experience you have to avoid synchronous execution which for example will block the UI. There is always a way to return the data asynchronously.